# MATLAB to C++ Mex Command Options

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have seen a lot information about how to use MATLAB coder to convert MATLAB codes to C++ code. Unfortunately, I do not have a license for coder. However, I recall back in my graduate studies in 2002-2003, I could use "mex" command with some specific options to convert MATLAB code to C and then make a executable.
Does anybody know those options? Is it possible that MATLAB make those command options obsolete and integrate everything inside coder?

Comment: Mex files are use to call C or C++ functions from a matlab code, not to generate a C code from a Matlab code

Comment: There was a time, long ago, that MATLAB Compiler would generate C code from MATLAB code, but I'm not sure it still did in 2002. The `mex` command never did this, all it does, and all it has ever done, is call the compiler and linker with the right settings to build your C or C++ or Fortran programs that link with MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I recall the command was mcc  and not mex.

Comment: I remember doing this too.  A command that compiles m-code functions directly into mex functions.  I just don't remember the details at the moment, or what add-ons you need (MATLAB Compiler?).  If I can find the details I will post them, but the last time I did this was probably 8-10 years ago.  I seem to recall the capability was intended primarily for embedded systems, and as such there were restrictions on having fixed types and sizes for inputs and outputs.